# how to handle multiple accounts on a single android app

Tags: android, authentication, firebase

I am trying to build an app in which there is a necessity of having multiple logins at a time and switching between accounts frequently like we have in gmail.
I have included the picture below having multiple accounts.
[image]

How to handle multiple accounts in such a way using firebase database.

Comment: what difficulty you are having to handle multiple accounts ?

Comment: What is the problem when handling multiple accounts ?